# KISS and DRY API design

Tags: api, rest, django-rest-framework, architecture, dry

I need to create a dashboard like page. It's not too complex. Think of it like a page with a single timeline chart, a couple of numbers and a few grids, [something like this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:3_Dashboards.JPG).

I already have a generic CRUD rest API for my data.

Should I create API methods specifically for this page, something like `getDashboardData`, etc., OR just call the MANY relevant crud API methods and process the data in the frontend/page?

What approach would you recommend from a point to view of creating a simple and manageable software architecture (DRY/KISS) and not specifically for performance/security reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** I would make dedicated reporting API's.

**Long answer (why):**

In general, system / solution design recognizes differences between transactional behavior/objectives and analytical behavior/objectives.  To understand that through a data lens take a look at [OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) vs [OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing).

As you seem to already recognize (or at least suspect), you can use your existing CRUD API's but they aren't an ideal fit, since they are orientated around transactions where as you want to do reporting across many transactions / records - you'll end-up having to make lots of requests which will put unnecessary load on your API and potentially any systems they connect to.

Because they will be purpose built, dedicated reporting API's should be better because:

- They provide the best opportunity to get the data you need, in the way you need it.  They will be designed in a way that makes them easy to call, and process the data that is returned.
- Their implementation can take the underlying data / systems into account and try to minimize impact on the source system.  For example, in "serious" scenarios you may decide to cache a copy of the data for reporting purposes so that any "heavy" reporting queries don't impact operational performance.  You can also change the structure of the data to make it more suited to reporting.
- Having a dedicated reporting API means you can choose who to expose that API to vs the other ones, apply different levels of security, etc.
- Having a dedicated reporting API adds some complexity and additional code to your solution, but provides a cleaner structure which should be easier to maintain.